# Построение Layout в Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

Всем привет! Недавно начал знакомится с ZF и начал писать первый проект на нем!

Возник вопрос такого плана:

Строю главную страницу сайта. Задача сделать сайт в 2 колонки, в левой контент выводится `indexContoller`'ом, в правой колонке форма авторизации и, допустим, 5 последних новостей ...

Как такое реализовать? Неужели все в один контроллер пихать и выводить как `$this->layout()->content`???

Мои мысли направлены, что может есть какой-то помощник вида, который, допустим, может вставить результат работы другого контроллера в layout допустим:

```
<div class="leftbar">
    <?=$this->layout()->content;?>
</div>
<div class="rightbar">
    <?=$this->layout()->viewHelper('controller', 'action');?> /*как то так чтоли*/
</div>
```

Что-то типо такого! Существует ли такое в zf или это реализуется по-другому?

Вопрос второй (если я правильно мыслю в первом вопросе): как подгружать разные лейоуты для разных контроллеров??? Для модулей уже знаю, а вот для контроллеров не могу придумать ...

```
public  function preDispatch()
{
    $bootstrap = $this -> getActionController()
    -> getInvokeArg('bootstrap');
    $config    = $bootstrap -> getOptions();
    $module    = $this -> getRequest()
    -> getControllerName();

    //проверяем есть ли гдето переменная и выводим нужный лейоут
    if(isset($layout){  
        $layoutScript = $layout;
        $this -> getActionController()
        -> getHelper('layout')
        -> setLayout($layoutScript);
    }
}
```

Конфиг у меня в `.ini`. Может как-то в него прописывать лейауты для разных контроллеров?

В общем, прошу помощи! Всем заранее огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

для начала не используй шот теги используй нормально `<?php ?>`

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151661/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-tag-in-php

а по твоему вопросу рекомендую для такой задачи не использовать layout. или можешь сделать контент такой какой есть, а в правую колонку подключи форму авторизации и вытаскивай из базы последние 5 новостей. Слева контент будет меняться, а с правой будет авторизация постоянно видна.
просто надо будет в зендовской форме указать обработчик формы.
религия тебе не запрещает вывести форму
пример будет такой

```
<div class="leftbar">
    <?php $this->layout()->content;?>
</div>
<div class="rightbar">
    <?php $form = new Application_Form_Temp();
       echo $form;/*форма/
   echo Zend_DB_Select()->select()->from('news')->order('timecreate desc')->limit('5');?>
</div>
```

но как на меня это плохо именно с базы вытаскивать в `layout`. будет грузить сайт
. с Оптимизацией подумай но идея моя такова.